# High RPM and drive mode malfucntion

Tags: tata, harrier

I have tata harrier bs4, MT 2018. RANDOMLY CAR SHOWS "DRIVE MODE MALFUNCTION" ERROR. AND ENGINE STARTS RUNNING AT 1500 RPM IF WE ARE DRIVING OR STANDSTILL when nutral or any forward direction gear is engaged. As we engage reverse gear or press brake pedal rpm come to normal ramge of 800-900. What could be the problem ? any help ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! T